# How to block specific URL in SquidGuard in pfSense?

Tags: squid, pfsense

I don't understand, how to utilize SquidGuard in pfSense?

Suppose I wish to ban domain `XXX.COM`

I go to `Target Categories` page and created new category `TestCategory` with the single domain `XXX.COM` inside.

The I go to `Common ACL` page and the open `Target Rules List` and enter `deny` into `TestCategory` row.

Is this correct?

Unfortunately, I am still able to open `XXX.COM` site.

Also I noticed some ambiguity in the configuration options: I can config redirect mode both on category page and on ACL page. How to know, which one works?

Comment: https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/SquidGuard_package  Bottom of the page - check the note about service not starting. You might also need to reload filters and reset states before your test is valid.

Comment: Service is running. This is probably me, who just don't know how to block address correctly

Answer (score 0):

welcome to pFsense!

Lets understand what you are doing:

The domain url is a https? Https on proxies does not work, you'll need block the IP of the domain or url on the firewall.

Which version of pFsense are you running?

Always, check stats of services, both squid and squidguard must be running

Srry for the bad english!